# SPANS não rotacionam com rotate e direcion dentro da LI

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte `código` abaixo:

```css
ul {
 width: 802px;
 list-style: none;
 border: .1px #000 solid;
 padding: 0;
}
ul#tabela {  
 height: 200px;
}
ul#retornos {  
 height: 30px;
}
ul li {
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 border-right: .1px #000 solid;
} 
ul li:last-child {
 border-right: none;
}
ul#tabela li span {
 font-weight: bolder;
 line-height: 30px;
}
ul#tabela li span.normal { 
 vertical-align: middle;
}
ul#tabela li span.vertical {
 width: 200px;
 direction: rtl;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul id='tabela'>
 <li style='width:100px;'><span class='normal'>Nome do Gcéu</span></li>
 <li style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Supervisor</span></li>
 <li style='width:100px;'><span class='normal'>Líder</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve Supervisão?</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de jejum?</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de evangelismo?</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Membros Compromissados</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Visitantes</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Crianças de 0 a 12 anos</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Total de presentes</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Ofertas</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Discipulados</span></li>
 <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Número de Decisões</span></li> 
</ul>
```

Gostaria de saber **porquê** os **spans** *NÃO* estão **rotacionando** e como **corrigir** isso.

Comment: Rapaz, mas vc já não tinha resolvido isso? :D

Comment: tive que alterar o jeito de fazer pois estou tendo problemas com mPDF que não aceita rosoa o css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elementos inline não podem ser rotacionados. Spans são elementos inline por padrão, forçando `display:block` ou `display:inline-block` no seu elemento a rotação funcionará.

Outra maneira é usando a rotação com base no elemento. Como exemplificado abaixo:

```css
ul {
  width: 850px;
  list-style: none;
  border: .1px #000 solid;
}

ul#tabela {
  height: 200px;
}

ul li {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-right: .1px #000 solid;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

ul#tabela li span.vertical {
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top 0;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 5px 25px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul id='tabela'>
  <li style='width:100px;'><span class='normal'>Nome do Gcéu</span></li>
  <li style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Supervisor</span></li>
  <li style='width:100px;'><span class='normal'>Líder</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve Supervisão?</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de jejum?</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de evangelismo?</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Membros Compromissados</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Visitantes</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Crianças de 0 a 12 anos</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Total de presentes</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Ofertas</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Discipulados</span></li>
  <li style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Número de Decisões</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Enttão, tem como inveter a posiçao do texto? ele está vrado da esquerda para a direita e de cima para baixo, gostaria o contrário. Mas atenção ao que vai acontecer com os sinais de interrogaçao. É necedsário também centralizar os spans dentro das li's  vetical e horizontalmente!

Comment: @CarlosRocha , sua pergunta é sobre o pq a rotação não ocorre. Creio que com a explicação acima sua dúvida foi sanada. Editei o trecho ajustando a rotação. A demonstração foi apenas para resolver o que você está tentando desenvolver. Basta usar o trecho e centralizar conforme a sua necessidade.